# Finding elementary function that gives a given Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, convolution

> How to prove that
> $$
> \left(\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos(2 n x)}{4 n^2 - 1} }\right)\cdot\left(\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin((2 n - 1) x)}{2 n - 1} }\right)  = \sin(x)\;?
> $$

We know that
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\lvert\sin(x)\rvert = \frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos(2 n x)}{4 n^2 - 1} }\\
\sgn(\sin(x)) = \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin((2 n - 1) x)}{2 n - 1} }$$
and the fact that
$$
\lvert\sin(x)\rvert \cdot \sgn(\sin(x))  = \sin(x)
$$

Comment: Do you know what is the Gibbs phenomenon in Fourier series?

Comment: Yes I am aware of it. I need some approximate method to work out a more complicated problem.